# Inno Setup not recognizing external file

Tags: inno-setup

In the process of deploying an app with Inno Setup I have to copy an external Access database (.accdb extension) from the same folder where the setup is located. If I try this in the [Files] section

```
Source: "{src}\FileName.accdb"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: external skipifsourcedoesntexist
```

the file never gets copied. However if I try for example

```
Source: "{src}\FileName.acc"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: external skipifsourcedoesntexist
```

after changing also the file extension, it gets copied correctly. This happens only when trying to copy an external file. Could it be a bug in Inno Setup that doesn't read the full file extension? Or am I doing something wrong? Any help would be very appreciated.

Comment: Cannot reproduce in Unicode Inno Setup 5.5.5. The file is copied properly even with the *.accdb extension.

Comment: You're right. There is no problem copying external files with the extension '.accdb'. However, external files with the extension '.accdr' dont' get copied ('.accdr' = Microsoft Access Runtime extension).
I gave the example with an '.accdb' file extension as it didn't occur to me that the problem could be the extension itself! I am also using Inno Setup 5.5.5 (u). Thank you.

Comment: Even a file with the *.accdr extension has no problem. And shouldn't have. I would suspect some security software that is blocking you to do that. Could you show the exact `[Files]` entry that you have ? Do you have any antivirus software that could block this operation ? Does your setup have sufficient privileges to copy to the target folder ? Can you copy such file from the command prompt ?

Comment: a) I have no antivirus or other security software installed. Even Windows Defender is disabled (Windows 7).

Comment: Well, and can you copy such file from the command prompt (from the exactly same source to the exactly same target with the same command prompt privileges) ?

Comment: (a) I have no antivirus or other security software installed. Even Windows Defender is disabled (Windows 7); (b) My [Files] entry is `Source: "{src}\Lic.accdr"; DestDir: "{app}\"; Flags: external ignoreversion skipifsourcedoesntexist`, but as pointed out it does not work with the file extension '.accdr'; (c) The file has no locks;  (d) This is my PC and I'm an administrator; (e) I can copy the file from the command prompt; (f) Tried to copy the '.accdr' file to/from different folders via Inno Setup, always unsuccessfully. (g) The setup is pretty large (over 30 files), everything else runs ok.

Answer (score 1):

You could try renaming the destination file using the DestName.

```
Source: "{src}\FileName.acc"; DestDir: "{app}"; DestName: "FileName.accdb"; Flags: external skipifsourcedoesntexist
```

Comment: That would be the way. But we should find the root of the problem, not provide a workaround for a problem that should not happen in the first place. If a file with such extension could not be copied by Inno Setup, it should be reported as a bug (and a serious one, if the OP mentions no exception raised at the installation time). I couldn't reproduce what's described and I suspect it's something on the machine that is deleting the file after the setup copies it to the target.

Comment: I agree, we should try to find the root cause. But in the meantime, this work around should allow you to make the installer work.